# Mongoose - Modle.update() updates wrong document - Cast Error

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I need some help to clear some things up.

**I have a Model:**

```
var Event = new Schema({
   event_code: String
 , segments: [Segment]
});
```

The creation of new documents work very well like perfect. When it comes to update certain documents I ran into some troubles.

**When I do this (code below):** = it only updates the first document, even if the id does not match

```
function edit_event (id, new_name, callback) {
  Event.update(id, {$set:{event_code: new_name}}, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) throw err;
    callback();
  });
}
```

**When I do this (code below):** = it gives me an Error (see below)

```
function edit_event (id, new_name, callback) {
  Event.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set:{event_code: new_name}}, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) throw err;
    callback();
  });
}
```

**Error when using findByIdAndUpdate:** `Cast to ObjectId failed for value ""58fdbde31bff83141b376508"" at path "_id" for model "Event"`

Please, i'm desperate :! :/

**UPDATE**

I figured out that the id that i'm trying to pass get stored with "" around it, so when i am looking for document with matching ID it puts an extra pair of "" around it so it ends up like ""id""

**UPDATE 2**

When I am listing all my documents, it returns:

```
{ _id: 58fdbde31bff83141b376508,

event_code: 'TestABC',

__v: 0,

segments: [] }
```

Then when i store the id in an HTML form it adds extra pair of "" around it ... that's not the case with event_code. Why is that ?

Comment: check whether you are passing right paramter for "id" when you are calling function edit_event,it should be string.

Comment: When you are working with find(),you should specify the parameter as {_id:id}... id is supplied by you.You need to specify key for which u want match.

Comment: I am passing the id as a string indeed. console.log(id); in the above example gives me 58fdbde31bff83141b376508 ... however I also tried to to '{_id:id}' = resulting in the same error

Comment: Oh No :/ ... it gives me the id as "58fdbde31bff83141b376508" sry ... how do i get rid of the " " brackets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you performed unneeded `JSON.stringify` and that's why you get quotes around the `id`. Calling `JSON.parse` should solve the issue:

`Event.findByIdAndUpdate(JSON.parse(id), {$set:{event_code: new_name}}, ...`

Comment: I guess that is it ! ... how do ended up with " " around the id in the first place ...i need to look out for that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, turned out i tried to store the id the wrong way into the HTML form ... which ended up in putting two pair of " " around it .... gosh i am so stupid ...